# How can I change the code of a component to get the data as array in react?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, react-hooks, next.js, drag-and-drop

I am trying to upload more than one image through this component but it only uploading one picture, how can I change my code to upload multiple images through drag and drop. Here is the code of my component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FileUploader } from "react-drag-drop-files";

const fileTypes = ["JPG", "PNG", "GIF"];

function ImageUpload() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const handleChange = (file) => {
    setFile(file);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {/* <h5>Drag and Drop Image</h5> */}
      <FileUploader handleChange={handleChange} name="file" types={fileTypes} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ImageUpload;
```

Answer (score 1):

add `multiple` attribute

```
  <FileUploader multiple handleChange={handleChange} name="file" types={fileTypes} />
```

handleChange will return a list of files from now